How can I fixColumn and adjust the content of fixedColumn columns?
Currently I am using a 3rd party datatable library.
Here is my configuration when re-rendering the mesh to start loading the input data.
_columns: is the list of columns I declared earlier
Code:
tbl.DataTable({...}).columns.adjust().draw();

And here is my result:


I want the result to not break the fixedColumn when adding new rows or adjusting the content of fixedColumn columns.
